# how to make a gallery from a plugin have blur fit for images instead of zoom fit

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I really liked smartslider 3 but its too heavy to load especially if i'm making 5-6 different galleries each with 60-80 images

i use Elementor to build the website and i found a plugin called **unlimited elements** from which they have some simple galleries but all are missing 1 thing

1- blur fit. and what that does is it fits all photos to the frame of the gallery without zooming in on the vertical shots to make them fit and blurs out the sides with the same image

i really want to know how i can i add this effect to the galleries in unlimited elements since they are editable with HTML or CSS. i tried copying the strings from the inspection window on smart slider 3 but nothing worked and its making me pull my hair.

The effect I need:

[image showing what my question is about]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pqr1.jpg

Comment: do you use a wordpress plugin to generate your gallery ?

Comment: yes i use ( unlimited elements ) its a plugin that is compatible with elementor

Comment: okay, but which plugin is it, that  you use for your gallery if you use any ?

Comment: the plugin is called " unlimited elements - widgets for elementor " im using the compact image gallery

Comment: okay, i see , are you allowed to modify it ?

Comment: https://unlimited-elements.com/ this the website for it

Comment: yes im allowed to edit the widget to my liking through HTML, CSS or javasript. checkout the attached i have in my answer below

Comment: you have access to the php code / template ? i do not know that tool

Comment: no, but i can export the widget if that helps. im not sure if i can post a zip file here

Comment: nop you canot, only share image. the best should to ask on a wordpress forum or make a new question about it wit the wordpress tag only.

Comment: the zip file has the following files:

addon.json
category.json
default_data.jason
html.tpl
html_item.tpl
js.tpl

Comment: what does the tool shows you when you click on HTML , is it your template ? maybe one could work from there ?

Comment: the file would be html.tpl probably . tpl for template

Comment: Widget HTML

<div id="{{uc_id}}" style="display:none;" >

    {{put_items()}}

</div>

Comment: Item HTML

<img alt="{{item.title}}"

     src="{{item.thumb}}"

     data-image="{{item.image}}"

     data-description="{{item.description}}">

Comment: okay then , html_item.tpl , from here you can copy the img tag twice, and then rework the css

Comment: this is inside the html.tpl 

<div id="{{uc_id}}" style="display:none;" >
 {{put_items()}}
</div>

Comment: this is inside html_item.tpl


<img alt="{{item.title}}"
     src="{{item.thumb}}"
     data-image="{{item.image}}"
     data-description="{{item.description}}">

Comment: is that all there is ? if so , you can make that image twice, and rework the css

Comment: jQuery(document).ready(function(){

  jQuery("#{{uc_id}}").unitegallery({
    gallery_theme:"compact",
    theme_panel_position: "{{cit_theme_panel_position}}",
    gallery_width:{{cit_gallery_width}},
    gallery_height:{{cit_gallery_height}},
    gallery_autoplay:{{cit_gallery_autoplay}},
    slider_transition: "{{cit_slider_transition}}",
    slider_enable_bullets: {{cit_enable_bullets}},
    thumb_width:{{cit_thumb_width}},
    slider_transition_speed:{{transition_speed}},

Comment: gallery_play_interval: {{interval}},
    gallery_shuffle:{{shuffle}},
    slider_control_zoom:{{zoom}},
    thumb_height:{{cit_thumb_height}}
  });

});

Comment: yes thats all thats there

Comment: im trying to look for a php file in the plugins folder

Comment: i guess from the template should do *html_item.tpl*, then it will be the css to adapt to set both img on top of each others

Comment: i found the gallery .css file

Comment: ill post the contents in a seperate answer

Comment: before starting editing, make a copy of the original files, if it goes wrong, then you have a backup to go back to normal ;)

Comment: it might deserve a new question , or edit yours

Comment: i won't be avalaible untill tomorrow now. hopefully someone else will be around.

Comment: ok thank you very much for you help and patience. what should i change the question to ?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199987/discussion-on-question-by-abdul-hammoude-how-to-make-a-gallery-from-a-plugin-hav).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use twice the same image, one can be blured and the other one on top of it.
filter is applied to the whole element and children(likewise opacity works) , so you need to select a single tag :

```css
body {margin:0}

div[class] {
  height: 480px;
  max-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
}
figure,
img {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  object-fit: cover;/* what you need */
  max-height: 100vh;
  max-width: 180vh;
}
figure {
}
img:first-of-type {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  filter: blur(4px);/* what you need */
}

/* demo purpose only to fake a gallery */
figure + figure {
  transform: translatey(-100%);
  margin-bottom: -100%;
}
figure:focus {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class>
  <figure >  <!-- both src value needs to be updated with the same image -->
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/640/480/nature">
</figure>
<figure tabindex="0"><!-- tabindex for the demo purpose -->
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/640/animals">
  <img src="https://placeimg.com/480/640/animals">
</figure>
</div>
```

Comment: <!-- both src value needs to be updated with the same image -->, so i have to do this with each image i have in the gallery ?

Comment: yes, i'll update the code with 2 image so you see better how it could work

Comment: @AbdulHammoude i updated the demo, run the snippet and click on the image to see the other one which has a different ratio .

Comment: this will take forever, i have about 300-400 images :S

Answer (score 0):

```
    ` 1st part of the code.---------Protection--------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper, 
.ug-gallery-wrapper *{
    transition: all !important;
    -o-transition: all !important;
    -webkit-transition: all;
    -moz-transition: all !important;
    -ms-transition: all !important;
    max-width:none;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper{
    z-index:0;
} 

.ug-item-wrapper img{
    width:auto;
    max-width:none;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.ug-videoplayer-wrapper video{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    visibility: visible !important;
}


.---------General_Styles--------{}

.ug-rtl{
    direction:rtl;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.ug-error-message{
    text-align:center;
    padding-top:30px;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#F30D0D;
}

.ug-error-message-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    border:1px solid black;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-canvas-pie{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:4;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-progress-bar{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:4;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-progress-bar-inner{
    xposition:absolute;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper.ug-fullscreen{
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    max-width:none !important;
    max-height:none !important;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper.ug-fake-fullscreen{
    position: fixed !important;
    height: auto !important;
    width: auto !important;
    max-width:none !important;
    max-height:none !important;
    margin: 0px !important;
    padding: 0px !important;
    top: 0px !important;
    left: 0px !important;
    bottom: 0px !important;
    right: 0px !important;
    z-index: 999999 !important;
}

.ug-body-fullscreen{
    overflow: hidden !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    width: 100% !important;
    margin:0px !important;
    padding:0px !important; 
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-preloader-trans{
    display:block;
    height:35px;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url('images/loader_skype_trans.gif');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}


.--------------SLIDER------------------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-slider-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    background-color:#000000;
}


.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-slide-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
}

.ug-slide-wrapper.ug-slide-clickable{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-slider-inner{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:0;
}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-item-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ug-slider-wrapper,
.ug-item-wrapper img{

    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* make unselectable */         
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none;  
    max-width:none !important;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-slider-preloader{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    border:2px solid #ffffff;
    border-radius:6px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    background-position:center center;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader1{
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url('images/loader-white1.gif');
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader1.ug-loader-black{
    background-image:url('images/loader-black1.gif');   
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader2{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url('images/loader-white2.gif');
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader2.ug-loader-black{
    background-image:url('images/loader-black2.gif');   
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader3{
    width:38px;
    height:38px;
    background-image:url('images/loader-white3.gif');
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader3.ug-loader-black{
    background-image:url('images/loader-black3.gif');   
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader4{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url('images/loader-white4.gif');
    background-color:white;
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader4.ug-loader-black{
    background-image:url('images/loader-black4.gif');   
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader5{
    width:60px;
    height:8px;
    background-image:url('images/loader-white5.gif');
    background-color:white;
    border:none;
    border-radius:0px;
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader5.ug-loader-black{
    background-image:url('images/loader-black5.gif');
    border:2px solid #000000;
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader6{
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
    background-image:url('images/loader-white6.gif');
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader6.ug-loader-black{
    background-image:url('images/loader-black6.gif');   
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader7{
    width:32px;
    height:10px;
    background-image:url('images/loader-white7.gif');
    border-width:3px;
    border-radius:3px;
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader7.ug-loader-black{
    background-image:url('images/loader-black7.gif');   
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader-black{
    border-color:#000000;
    background-color:#000000;
}

.ug-slider-preloader.ug-loader-nobg{
    background-color:transparent;
}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-button-videoplay{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    cursor:pointer; 
}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-button-videoplay.ug-type-square{ 
    width:86px;
    height:66px;
    background-image:url('images/play-button-square.png');
    background-position:0px -66px;
}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-button-videoplay.ug-type-square.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px 0px;
}


.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-button-videoplay.ug-type-round{  
    width:76px;
    height:76px;
    background-image:url('images/play-button-round.png');
    opacity:0.9;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s !important;
}


.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-button-videoplay.ug-type-round.ug-button-hover{
    opacity:1;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 100);
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s !important;
}


.--------------VIDEO_PLAYER------------------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-videoplayer{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;    
    background-color:#000000;
    background-image:url('images/loader-black1.gif');   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}

.ug-videoplayer .ug-videoplayer-wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    background-image:url('images/loader-black1.gif');   
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}


.ug-videoplayer .ug-videoplayer-button-close{
    position:absolute;
    height:64px;
    width:64px;
    background-image:url('images/button-close.png');
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:1000;
}


.ug-videoplayer .ug-videoplayer-button-close:hover{
    background-position: 0px -64px;
}

.--------------THUMBS_STRIP------------------{}


.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-thumbs-strip,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-thumbs-grid{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* make unselectable */         
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none;

    xbackground-color:green;
    z-index:10;
}

.ug-thumbs-strip.ug-dragging{
    xcursor: -webkit-grab;
    xcursor: -moz-grab;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-thumbs-strip-inner,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-thumbs-grid-inner{
    position:absolute;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;

    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* make unselectable */         
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none;

    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
}


.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated .ug-thumb-loader,
.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated .ug-thumb-error{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:center center;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper .ug-thumb-border-overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:4;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    border-style:solid;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper .ug-thumb-overlay{
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:3;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated .ug-thumb-loader-dark{
    background-image:url('images/loader.gif');
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated .ug-thumb-loader-bright{
    background-image:url('images/loader_bright.gif');
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated .ug-thumb-error{
    background-image:url('images/not_loaded.png');
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated img{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:1;
    max-width:none !important;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-thumb-generated img.ug-thumb-image-overlay{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
    max-width:none !important;
}


/* bw desaturate effect lightweight */
img.ug-bw-effect{
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'grayscale\'><feColorMatrix type=\'matrix\' values=\'0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0.3333 0.3333 0.3333 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\'/></filter></svg>#grayscale"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */  
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%); 
}

/* blur effect desaturate effect lightweight */
img.ug-blur-effect{

    filter: blur(0.8px); 
    -webkit-filter: blur(0.8px);
    -moz-filter: blur(0.8px);
    -o-filter: blur(0.8px);
    -ms-filter: blur(0.8px);    
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id='blur'><feGaussianBlur stdDeviation=\'0.8\' /></filter></svg>#blur"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Blur(PixelRadius='0.8');
}

img.ug-sepia-effect{
    -webkit-filter: sepia(1);
    -webkit-filter: sepia(100%); -moz-filter: sepia(100%);
    -ms-filter: sepia(100%); -o-filter: sepia(100%);
    filter: url("data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg xmlns=\'http://www.w3.org/2000/svg\'><filter id=\'sepia\'><feColorMatrix values=\'0.14 0.45 0.05 0 0 0.12 0.39 0.04 0 0 0.08 0.28 0.03 0 0 0 0 0 1 0\' /></filter></svg>#sepia"); /* Firefox 10+, Firefox on Android */
    filter: sepia(100%);
    background-color: #5E2612;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
    zoom:1;
}


.--------------BULLETS------------------{}


.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-bullets{
    position: absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-bullets .ug-bullet{
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
    float:left;
    z-index:2;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-bullets .ug-bullet:first-child{
    margin-left:0px;
}


.--------------TEXT_PANEL------------------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-textpanel{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-textpanel{
    z-index:2;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-textpanel-bg,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-textpanel-title,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-textpanel-description{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}


.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-textpanel-bg{
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 40);
    z-index:1;
}

.ug-textpanel-textwrapper{
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-textpanel-title{
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:2;  
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-textpanel-description{
    font-size:14px;
    color:white;
    text-align:left;
    z-index:3;
}


.--------------ZOOM_PANEL------------------{}

.ug-slider-wrapper .ug-zoompanel{
    position:absolute;
    top:200px;
    left:100px;
}

.ug-zoompanel .ug-zoompanel-button{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    display:block;
}


.--------------ZOOM_PANEL_BUTTONS------------------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-arrow-left{
    position:absolute;  
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    display:block;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-arrow-right{
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
}


.--------------GRID_PANEL_AND_ARROWS------------------{}


.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel{
    position:absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    xbackground-color: blue;

    z-index:2;
}


.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow{
    position:absolute;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    z-index:11;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow.ug-button-disabled{
    cursor:default; 
}


/* handle tip */
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-panel-handle-tip{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:13;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-overlay-disabled{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity: 0.3;
    filter: alpha(opacity=30);  
    background-image:url('images/cover-grid.png');
}


.--------------STRIP_PANEL------------------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-strip-panel{
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000000;
    z-index:2;
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow{
    position:absolute;  
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow.ug-button-disabled{
    cursor:default;
}


.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    position:absolute;
}

.--------------TILES------------------{}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    overflow:hidden;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
}

.ug-tile .ug-tile-cloneswrapper{
    position:absolute;
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    overflow:hidden;
    opacity:0;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 90);
}


/* transit something */
/* transit fixed size items */
/* transit image overlay */

.ug-tiles-transit.ug-tiles-transition-active .ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile,
.ug-tiles-transit.ug-tiles-transition-active .ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-trans-enabled{
    transition: left 0.7s ease 0s, top 0.7s ease 0s, width 0.7s ease 0s, height 0.7s ease 0s !important;
}


.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile.ug-tile-clickable{
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-image-container{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:1;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile img.ug-thumb-image{

    -webkit-user-select: none;  /* make unselectable */         
    -moz-user-select: none; 
    -ms-user-select: none;  
    max-width:none !important;
    max-height:none !important;

    display:block;  
    border:none;
    padding:0px !important;
    margin:0px !important;

    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
}


.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-image-overlay{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    z-index:2;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-image-overlay img{
    width:100%;
    max-width:none !important;  
}

.ug-tiletype-justified .ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-image-overlay img{
    height:100%;
    max-width:none !important;  
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-icon{
    position:absolute;
    width:38px;
    height:38px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0 0;
    xbackground-color:green;
    z-index:6;
    top:1px;
    left:1px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-icon.ug-icon-link{
    background-image:url('images/icon-link32.png'); 
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-icon.ug-icon-zoom{
    background-image:url('images/icon-zoom32.png'); 
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-icon.ug-icon-play{
    background-image:url('images/icon-play32.png'); 
}

.ug-thumb-wrapper.ug-tile .ug-tile-icon:hover{
    background-position:0 -38px;
}


.ug-thumbs-grid .ug-tile-image-overlay img{
    width:auto;
    height:auto;
    position:absolute;
    max-width:none !important;
}

/* text panel on tiles*/

.ug-tile .ug-textpanel{
    z-index: 5;
    cursor:default;
}

.ug-tile.ug-tile-clickable .ug-textpanel{
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ug-tile .ug-textpanel-title{
    font-size:14px;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.--------------CAROUSEL------------------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-carousel-wrapper{
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-carousel-inner{
    position:absolute;
}


.------------------LIGHTBOX---------------------{}

.ug-gallery-wrapper.ug-lightbox{
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    border: none;
    padding:0px;
    margin:0px;
    outline: invert none medium;
    overflow: hidden;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-width:none !important;
    max-height:none !important;
    z-index: 999999;
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-top-panel{
    position:absolute;
    z-index:2;
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-top-panel-overlay{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:0.4;
    filter: alpha(opacity=40);
}


.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-overlay{
    z-index:1;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color:#000000;
    opacity:1;
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-slider-wrapper{
    z-index:1;
    xbackground-color:green;
    background-color:transparent !important;
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-textpanel{
    z-index: 2;
}


.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-arrow-left,
.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-arrow-right{
    position:absolute;
    width:50px;
    height:55px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url('images/lightbox-arrow-left.png');
    background-position:0px 0px;
    z-index:3;
    cursor:pointer;
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-arrow-right{
    background-image:url('images/lightbox-arrow-right.png');
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-button-close{
    position:absolute;
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-image:url('images/lightbox-icon-close.png');
    background-position:0px 0px;
    z-index:4;
    cursor:pointer;
}


.ug-lightbox-compact .ug-lightbox-button-close{
    width:45px;
    height:41px;
    background-image:url('images/lightbox-icon-close-compact2.png');
}


.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-arrow-left.ug-arrow-hover,
.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-arrow-right.ug-arrow-hover{
    background-position:0px -55px;  
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-button-close.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -35px;
}

.ug-lightbox-compact .ug-lightbox-button-close.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -40px;
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-lightbox-numbers{
    position:absolute;
    color:#e5e5e5;
    font-size:12px;
    top:14px;
    left:8px;
    z-index:3;
}

.ug-lightbox-compact .ug-lightbox-numbers{
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-top:7px;
}

.ug-lightbox .ug-textpanel-title,
.ug-lightbox .ug-textpanel-description{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    color: #e5e5e5;
}

.ug-lightbox-compact .ug-textpanel-title,
.ug-lightbox-compact .ug-textpanel-description{
    color:#F3F3F3;
    font-size: 16px;
}

.------------------LOADMORE_BUTTON---------------------{}

.ug-loadmore-wrapper{
    margin-top:20px;
    text-align:center;  
}

.ug-loadmore-wrapper .ug-loadmore-button{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:5px;
    border:1px solid #939393;
    text-decoration:none;
    color: #4F4F4F;
}

.ug-loadmore-wrapper .ug-loadmore-error{
    color:red;
}

.ug-loadmore-wrapper .ug-loadmore-button:hover{
    background-color:#F0F0F0;   
    color:#515151;
}

.ug-loadmore-wrapper .ug-loadmore-loader{
    color: #515151;
}



.------------------CATEGORY_TABS---------------------{}

    .ug-tabs-wrapper{
        margin-top:0px;
        margin-bottom:20px;
        text-align:center;
    }

    .ug-tabs-wrapper a.ug-tab{
        display: inline-block;
        cursor:pointer;
        text-decoration:none;
        color:#ffffff;
        padding-left:8px;
        padding-right:8px;
        padding-top:6px;
        padding-bottom:6px;
        margin-left:5px;
        background-color:#333333;
        border-radius:3px;
        font-size:12px;
        font-weight:normal;

        border: 1px solid #969696;
    }

    .ug-tabs-wrapper a.ug-tab:hover{
        background-color: #707070 !important;
    }

    .ug-tabs-wrapper a.ug-tab.ug-tab-selected,
    .ug-tabs-wrapper a.ug-tab.ug-tab-selected:hover{
        background-color: #2077A2 !important;
        cursor:default !important;
    }

    .ug-tabs-wrapper a.ug-tab:first-child{
        margin-left:0px !important;
    }


`
```

Answer (score 0):

```
`    this is the second part of the code.------------------DEFAULT_SKIN---------------------{}

/* --- arrows -- */

.ug-arrow-left.ug-skin-default,
.ug-arrow-right.ug-skin-default{
    width:15px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url('images/slider_arrow_left.png');
    background-position:0px 0px;
}

.ug-arrow-right.ug-skin-default{
    background-image:url('images/slider_arrow_right.png');
}

.ug-arrow-left.ug-skin-default.ug-arrow-hover,
.ug-arrow-right.ug-skin-default.ug-arrow-hover{
    background-position:0px -30px;
}

.ug-arrow-left.ug-skin-default.ug-arrow-disabled,
.ug-arrow-right.ug-skin-default.ug-arrow-disabled{
    background-position:0px -60px;
}

/* --- bullets -- */

.ug-bullets.ug-skin-default .ug-bullet{
    width:15px;
    height:15px;
    background-image:url('images/slider_bullets.png');
    background-position:top left;
    margin-left:5px;
}

.ug-bullets.ug-skin-default .ug-bullet.ug-bullet-active{
    background-position:bottom left;
}

.ug-bullets.ug-skin-default.ug-bullets-gray .ug-bullet{ 
    background-image:url('images/tile_bullets_gray.png');
}

.ug-bullets.ug-skin-default.ug-bullets-blue .ug-bullet{ 
    background-image:url('images/tile_bullets_blue.png');
}

.ug-bullets.ug-skin-default.ug-bullets-brown .ug-bullet{ 
    background-image:url('images/tile_bullets_brown.png');
}

.ug-bullets.ug-skin-default.ug-bullets-green .ug-bullet{ 
    background-image:url('images/tile_bullets_green.png');
}

.ug-bullets.ug-skin-default.ug-bullets-red .ug-bullet{ 
    background-image:url('images/tile_bullets_red.png');
}

.ug-button-tile-navigation{
    width:36px;
    height:36px;
    background-position:top left;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-tile-left{
    background-image:url('images/tile_button_left.png');
}

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-tile-right{
    background-image:url('images/tile_button_right.png');
}

.ug-button-tile-navigation:hover{
    background-position:bottom left;
}

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-disabled{
    opacity:0.6;
}

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-disabled:hover{
    background-position:top left;   
}

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-tile-play{
    background-image:url('images/tile_button_play_pause.png');
    width:35px;
} 

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-tile-play.ug-pause-icon{
    background-position:bottom left;
} 

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-tile-play:hover{
    background-position:top left;
} 

.ug-button-tile-navigation.ug-button-tile-play.ug-pause-icon:hover{
    background-position:bottom left;
} 


/* --- play button -- */

.ug-button-play.ug-skin-default{
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('images/button_playpause.png');
    width:14px;
    height:17px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}

.ug-button-play.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -17px;  
}

.ug-button-play.ug-skin-default.ug-stop-mode{
    background-position:0px -34px;
}

.ug-button-play.ug-skin-default.ug-stop-mode.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -51px;
}

/* --- fullscreen button -- */

.ug-button-fullscreen.ug-skin-default{
    position:absolute;
    background-image:url('images/button_fullscreen.png');
    width:16px;
    height:16px;
    cursor:pointer;
    background-position:0px 0px;
}

.ug-button-fullscreen.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -16px;  
}

.ug-button-fullscreen.ug-skin-default.ug-fullscreenmode{
    background-position:0px -32px;
}

.ug-button-fullscreen.ug-skin-default.ug-fullscreenmode.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -48px;
}


/* --- zoom panel --- */

.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-button{
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    cursor:pointer;
    height: 23px;
    width: 23px;
    margin-top:5px;
    background-position: 0px 0px;   
}

.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-plus{
    margin-top:0px;
}

.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-plus{
    background-image:url('images/icon_zoom_plus.png');
}

.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-minus{
    background-image:url('images/icon_zoom_minus.png');
}

.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-return{
    background-image:url('images/icon_zoom_back.png');
}

.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-button.ug-button-hover{
    background-position: 0px -23px;
}

.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-button-disabled,
.ug-zoompanel.ug-skin-default .ug-zoompanel-button.ug-button-hover.ug-zoompanel-button-disabled{
    background-position: 0px -46px;
    cursor:default;
}


/* --- Grid Panel Arrows -- */

/*--- down arrow ---*/

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-down.ug-skin-default{
    width:30px;
    height:15px;
    background-position:0px 0px;    
    background-image:url('images/arrow_grid_down.png');
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-down.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -15px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-down.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover.ug-button-disabled,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-down.ug-skin-default.ug-button-disabled{
    background-position:0px -30px;
}


/*--- up arrow ---*/

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-up.ug-skin-default{
    width:30px;
    height:15px;
    background-position:0px 0px;    
    background-image:url('images/arrow_grid_up.png');
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-up.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -15px;  
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-up.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover.ug-button-disabled,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-up.ug-skin-default.ug-button-disabled{
    background-position:0px -30px;
}

/*--- left arrow ---*/

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left.ug-skin-default{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-position:0px -40px;
    background-image:url('images/grid_arrow_left.png');
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover.ug-button-disabled,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left.ug-skin-default.ug-button-disabled{
    background-position:0px -80px;
}

/*--- right arrow ---*/

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right.ug-skin-default{
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    background-position:0px -40px;  
    background-image:url('images/grid_arrow_right.png');
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover.ug-button-disabled,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right.ug-skin-default.ug-button-disabled{
    background-position:0px -80px;
}

/*--- left arrow - horizontal panel type ---*/

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left-hortype.ug-skin-default{
    width:15px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url('images/slider_arrow_left.png');
    background-position:0px 0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left-hortype.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -30px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left-hortype.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover.ug-button-disabled,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-left-hortype.ug-skin-default.ug-button-disabled{
    background-position:0px -60px;
}


/*--- right arrow - horizontal panel type ---*/

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right-hortype.ug-skin-default{
    width:15px;
    height:30px;
    background-image:url('images/slider_arrow_right.png');
    background-position:0px 0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right-hortype.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -30px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right-hortype.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover.ug-button-disabled,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-grid-panel .grid-arrow-right-hortype.ug-skin-default.ug-button-disabled{
    background-position:0px -60px;
}


/* --- Strip Panel Arrows -- */

/* left and right arrows */

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-left.ug-skin-default,
.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-right.ug-skin-default{
    width:25px;
    height:50px;
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-left.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip,
.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-right.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:4px;
    height:7px;
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-left.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-image:url('images/arrows_strip_left.png');
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-right.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-image:url('images/arrows_strip_right.png');  
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-left.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover .ug-strip-arrow-tip,
.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-right.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-position:0px -7px;
}


/* up and down arrows */

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-up.ug-skin-default,
.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-down.ug-skin-default{
    height:25px;
    width:50px;
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-up.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip,
.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-down.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-position:0px 0px;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    width:7px;
    height:4px;
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-up.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-image:url('images/arrows_strip_up.png');
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-down.ug-skin-default .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-image:url('images/arrows_strip_down.png');   
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-up.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover .ug-strip-arrow-tip,
.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow-down.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-position:-7px 0px;
}

.ug-strip-panel .ug-strip-arrow.ug-skin-default.ug-button-disabled .ug-strip-arrow-tip{
    background-position:0px 0px;
    opacity:0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity = 50);
}


/* --- Panel Handle Tip -- */

/* left and right handle */
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-left.ug-skin-default,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-right.ug-skin-default{
    width:22px;
    height:36px;
    background-image:url('images/grid_handle_black_left.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:0px -36px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-right.ug-skin-default{
    background-image:url('images/grid_handle_black_right.png');
    background-position:0px -36px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-left.ug-button-hover.ug-skin-default,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-right.ug-button-hover.ug-skin-default{
    background-position:0px -0px;   
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-left.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-right.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed{
    background-position:0px -108px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-left.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed.ug-button-hover,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-right.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px -72px;
}


/* top and bottom handle */

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-top.ug-skin-default,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-bottom.ug-skin-default{  
    width:36px;
    height:22px;
    background-image:url('images/grid_handle_black_top.png');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:-36px 0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-bottom.ug-skin-default{
    background-image:url('images/grid_handle_black_bottom.png');
    background-position:-36px 0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-top.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-bottom.ug-skin-default.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:0px 0px;    
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-top.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-bottom.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed{
    background-position:-108px 0px;
}

.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-top.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed.ug-button-hover,
.ug-gallery-wrapper .ug-handle-tip-bottom.ug-skin-default.ug-button-closed.ug-button-hover{
    background-position:-72px 0px;
}
```

`